# Default mysql user is empty string. How do I change it to be "me" (i.e. whoami)

Tags: macos, mysql

I recently updated my OS from Mavericks to Yosemite, and now when I do `mysql foo` I get:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'foo'
```

This used to run mysql with my username, as per `whoami`, as the mysql user. How do I make it do so again? (without passing a `-u` argument)

**UPDATE**
Seems it is reducing my username to an empty string, even if I provide it explicitly.

```
nickshanks$ mysql -u nickshanks foo
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'foo'
nickshanks$ mysql -u "'nickshanks'@'localhost'" foo
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'foo'
```

Everything works fine if I log in to the MySQL prompt as `root`.

Answer (score 1):

In your home directory create a file `.my.cnf`. This is of the "ini" format with section support. Set any defaults for client programs under the client section. Options for specific programs can be given in a section named identical to the program name.

Options are named after the long option for the program (without the first two dashes, as they are part of getopt(3) and not part of the name).

So, a good base is this (note that it hardcodes the username):

```
cat <<EOF >~.my.cnf
[client]
user = $USER
database = $USER

EOF
```

Alternatively, if your true intent is to have it be identical to the user that is invoking the program, I suspect MySQL to look at a certain environment variable if no user is given. I can't find this in the documentation, but it's probably looking at $USER, which would mean the above snippet would create empty values and would explain the change in behavior after upgrade.

Check with `env` if your username is present in a variable. If not, setup $ USER and $USERNAME as an alternative in your shell rc file (.bashrc, .zshrc, .profile or what ever applies). Don't forget to relog after change, or set them up runtime via export or setenv.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. My normal user privileges were for host '127.0.0.1' (set because localhost used to not resolve properly in some instances). I logged in as root and changed them all to localhost and all my databases showed up again when logged in unprivileged. But kudos to Melvin for having a stab at figuring it out remotely.